# Solving OOM Issue for a spark Job

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to figure out why my executors are giving out of memory issues. My command to run the spark job is

```
./bin/spark-submit --class com.company.dept.job.SparkJob \
       --executor-memory 13G  --num-executors 54 --driver-memory 30G --executor-cores 1 \
       --conf spark.security.credentials.hadoop.enabled=true \
       --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=2048 \
       --conf spark.files.maxPartitionBytes=16777216 \
       --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/opt/spark/work-dir/shared/log4j.properties' \
       --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions='-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/opt/spark/work-dir/shared/log4j.properties -Ddatastax-java-driver.basic.request.timeout=10000' \
       work-dir/shared/deepak/myjar.jar
```

**My observation**

1. I've noted a significant difference between the data's input and output sizes and the memory allocation for the job.
2. Interestingly, the tasks that failed did not request more memory in comparison to those that succeeded.
3. During my experimentation, I initiated a job with a smaller input dataset, and it executed successfully. However, as the dataset size grew, the number of failing tasks also increased. Given that I've specified the maxPartitionBytes parameter to maintain a constant data size per task, I'm puzzled about the root cause of this memory problem.

I am attaching the screenshots of my spark UI

[image]

Details about a failed executor

[image]

Details about a successful executor (The first pod is a driver pod)

[image]

Can you please guide me regarding solving this issue ? Is there some metric which I missed while analysing the OOM issue ?

**Complete Code**
I have changed the code a little bit to remove company specific stuff

```java
    public static void main(@NotNull String[] args) throws NoSuchTableException {
        log.info("Starting the spark job {}", SparkJob.class.getName());
        LocalDate jobStartTime = LocalDate.of(2021, 4, 1);

        for (int month = 8; month <= 14; month++) {
            String sparkAppName = generateSparkAppName("feat-" + month);
            SparkConf sparkConf = getSparkConf(sparkAppName);
            SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();
            final LongAccumulator accumulator = sparkSession.sparkContext().longAccumulator("Successful Processed Count");
            LocalDate startDate = jobStartTime.plusMonths(month - 1);
            LocalDate endDate = jobStartTime.plusMonths(month);

            log.info("Calculating the feature values for the start date {} to end date {}", startDate, endDate);
            Dataset<Row> rows = sparkSession.table(MY_TABLE)
                .select(new Column(COLUMN_1), new Column(COLUMN_2), new Column(COLUMN_3),
                    new Column(PARTITION_KEY), new Column(COLUMN_4))
                .filter("yyyy_mm_dd >= '" + startDate + "' AND yyyy_mm_dd < '" + endDate + "'");
    // Get Features is a UDF which performs some operation on each row
            Dataset<Tuple2<Boolean, String>> processedRows = rows.mapPartitions(new GetFeatures(accumulator),
                Encoders.tuple(Encoders.BOOLEAN(), Encoders.STRING()));
            processedRows.persist();

            Dataset<Row> successfulRows = processedRows.filter((FilterFunction<Tuple2<Boolean, String>>) booleanRowTuple2 -> booleanRowTuple2._1).map(
                (MapFunction<Tuple2<Boolean, String>, Row>) booleanRowTuple2 -> mapToRow(booleanRowTuple2._2, getSchema()), RowEncoder.apply(getSchema()));

            Dataset<Row> failedRows = processedRows.filter((FilterFunction<Tuple2<Boolean, String>>) booleanRowTuple2 -> !booleanRowTuple2._1).map(
                (MapFunction<Tuple2<Boolean, String>, Row>) booleanRowTuple2 -> mapToRow(booleanRowTuple2._2, getFailureSchema()),
                RowEncoder.apply(getFailureSchema()));

            successfulRows.write()
                .partitionBy(PARTITION_KEY)
                .format("hive")
                .mode("append")
                .saveAsTable("deepak.features");
            failedRows.write()
                .partitionBy(PARTITION_KEY)
                .format("hive")
                .mode("append")
                .saveAsTable("deepak.failed_rows");
            processedRows.unpersist();
            log.info("Completed the spark job with success count {} for the start date {} to end date {}", accumulator.value(),
                startDate, endDate);
            sparkSession.close();
        }
```

Error Log

```
The executor with id 3 exited with exit code 137(SIGKILL, possible container OOM). 
The API gave the following container statuses: 
...

container name: spark-kubernetes-executor 
container image: <container-image> 
container state: terminated container started at: 2023-09-17T07:43:10Z container finished at: 2023-09-17T10:10:23Z exit code: 137 termination reason: OOMKilled 
....
```

Comment: Can you share your code and the full error stack trace you're getting?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, I have added the complete code and the stack trace from spark UI

Comment: `OOMKilled` could be a message from Kubernetes. Maybe your Spark configuration is fine but one of your executor pods exeeds Kubernetes [memory limit](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/)?

Comment: I checked the limit and request of the container running spark

    Limits:
      cpu:     2
      memory:  15Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:     1
      memory:  15Gi
The limit and requests looks good

Comment: `spark.executor.memoryOverhead` + `executor-memory` is 15 G. Could you increase the Kubernetes memory limits a bit just to see what happens? Not sure if the VM sometimes consumes a bit more memory than configured.

Comment: Nice idea, will give it a try!!

Comment: Increasing the memoryOverhead to --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=3000  solved the issue. This was not visible from the spark UI that I should increase the memory overhead